# Short story in which a spacecraft is destroyed when all its internal friction is removed, so that it falls apart

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

It's a short story in which a spacecraft is destroyed when all its internal friction is removed, so that it falls apart. I think the friction-removal device might have been a weapon.

Comment: Do you remember anything else about it? When you read it, language, was it part of a collection etc?

Comment: Was the story in comic book format?
Did it start with a scene of the protagonist on vacation in a country cottage?
But the next panel was zoomed out showing that the cottage was inside a habitat in a space station?

Comment: @Mike If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark next to the answer of your choice. If not, you might try providing more details about the story you're looking for, such as when you read it.

Comment: Question for the Closing Crew: Why does the question need more details? How many stories are there in which spaceships are destroyed by a friction-removal device? I bet most people would be hard pressed to name more than four or five. Not being widely read, I only know of one of them, which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 24):

["Frictional Losses"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47944), a novelette by [John W. Campbell, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_W._Campbell), first published (as by "Don A. Stuart") in [*Astounding Stories*, July 1936](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57513+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v17n05_1936-07_frankenscan/page/n45/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?47944).

> Man has always thought of friction as his worst enemy, yet he cannot do without it. Look, your clothes fell apart in a moment, because the woven strands were held together by their friction. Even the knots were held by friction. The shed fell on us, as the house fell, because the friction that held the nails in was gone, and the nails, of course, sprang out. I was vastly tempted to turn it on the Diesel, and get along without oil, till I remembered—every bolt and nut would fly off as though a charge of explosive lay beneath it, for each bolt and each nut is held in place only by friction. In a hundredth of a second the Diesel would have become a mass of disassembled, oil-splattered parts.

The "anti-friction projector" is used as a weapon to destroy the
spaceships of alien invaders:

> An unbearable violet flame leaped suddenly in the skies, shrieking a thousand feet in the air. A rain of black metal separated from a solid clump to spread in a long, stretching line that reached down and down in masses to the waiting earth. It settled at the base of a giant
> rock, finally, as a second long rain of metal reached down and down.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "There were eight here, thirty more came this morning. Detroit has sent
> three of the rocket machines, and five of the frictionless, welded tank machines have crossed the country. They left an anti-friction projector set in each clan village they passed.

From review by [Everett F. Bleiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._F._Bleiler) in [*Science-Fiction: The Gernsback Years*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29232):

> Time: presumably the late twentieth century.
>
> Background: About thirty years earlier one hundred great Granthee spaceships invaded the Earth. The Granthee, who were sixlegged monstrosities of undisclosed origin, possessed heat rays, atomic bombs, atomic power and other appurtenances of superior science, but were gradually destroyed.
>
> The cost, however, was high. Granthee atomic bombs turned cities and fortresses into lava pools, and rays exterminated the peoples of Asia and most of Europe. North America, while somewhat less hard hit, still suffered severely. Approximately 99.9% of the human race perished in repelling the invasion, and the survivors have relapsed nearly into primitivism.
>
> The few men who try to recover the ancient science, including atomic bombs created toward the last of the invasion, are reduced to digging in the rubble of ruined cities for materials and growing castor beans for oil. Erratic radio, relapsed to Morse code, exists between such scattered establishments.
>
> In the former New York area, old Hugh and his young friend Tom scavenge for radio parts. Hugh has the unrealistic hope of building weapons against the expected second invasion by the Granthee, but Tom and most of the others in their small settlement regard Hugh's work askance and are fatalistic about what they know is inevitable death.
>
> While puttering with high frequency currents, however, Hugh accidentally constructs a device that destroys friction in the path of its emanations. This comes in the nick of time, just as the ships of the second Granthee invasion are overhead. Hugh has broadcast details of his invention, and the Granthee ships are no more than clay pigeons.

Comment: I'm not a physicist but I struggle to see how all the bolts would immediately and explosively unscrew without friction.

Comment: @Whelkaholism you spin them quickly and they pull themselves in. Friction is the only thing stopping that from being reversible - so you pull them apart and they spin quickly the other way and come apart.

Comment: @Whelkaholism, I think the assumption is that the diesel engine is running at the time.  _Any_ internal combustion engine operates on the principle of explosive expansion of combustion gases, and thus a running engine contains high pressures.  Remove the friction, and those pressures would force all the nuts, bolts, and other connectors to disassemble — explosively.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly Allen Dean Foster's *[Slipt](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1133570)*

> Living next to a toxic chemical dump is Jake Pickett, the magic man. He can turn bullets to dust or collapse skyscrapers with his mind. But all he really wants to do with his "magic" is entertain the local kids. Then one day, the giant chemical company decides to eliminate the people who have been affected by their mess--people like Jay.

[This Spacebattles thread](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/what-exactly-would-happen-if-you-turned-off-friction.253379/) mentions him making guns fall apart by turning off the friction for the fasteners.

> In the Alan Dean Foster novel Slipt, the main character had this power. He pulled off tricks like making bad guy's guns fall apart because the screws no longer held them together. Lots of fasteners rely on friction to work.

Not matching is that I don't see any mention of spaceships.